# Add dss dictionary

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, pdfbox

I'm using pdfBox to complete a pades document with the revocation information. The objective is that the document becomes LTV enabled.

The document I'am using has 1 signature and one timestamp. I've got the necessary crl/ocsp tokens.

My question is how I can I construct an COSDictionary having the response from CRL and OCSP?

```
InMemoryDocument doc = new InMemoryDocument(getFile());
PDDocument document = PDDocument.loadNonSeq(doc.openStream(), null);

COSDictionary cosDictionary = document.getDocumentCatalog().getCOSDictionary();
...

cosDictionary.setNeedToBeUpdate(true);
```

Thanks

Comment: Your use of `InMemoryDocument` seems to indicate you use the EU joinup sd-dss. The current 4.5-SNAPSHOT development version of that project uses PDFBox 1.8.8. I've not yet seen a clean way to use the PDFBox 1.8.x incremental update mechanism for anything but adding signatures. If I understand you correctly, though, you want to add validation related information in a DSS dictionary without adding a document timestamp. Thus, you need an incremental update. I'm afraid there is no easy way to do it, you might have to improve PDFBox a bit for that.

Comment: yes I'm using sd-dss to extend documents to LTA level. 
For example I've got a document that has 1 signature and 1 timestamp from an TSA. In this case the person who did the signature didn't include the revocation information. So the adobe will say that the signature isn't LTV enabled but the timestamp is. My question is how I can add the revocation information about the signature to the DSS dictionary.

Comment: I'll try and look into this during the long weekend to start now. As mentioned above, I have not yet seen an easy way to achieve what is needed, i.e. incrementally updating with PDFBox for something else than a signature.

Comment: Thanks.
I've added the necessary information to the DSS but it's not an elegant solution. I've had to slighty change the dss-documenbt library.

Comment: *I've added the necessary information to the DSS but it's not an elegant solution.* - if you added your code, it would be easier to tell whether your solution (albeit probably not elegant) is the best solution using PDFBox or no.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have the necessary certificates, CRLs, and OCSP responses available as byte arrays, you can add them to a Document Security Store like this using PDFBox:

```java
COSDictionary dss = createDssDictionary(certificates, crls, ocspResponses);
```

making use of these helper methods:

```java
COSDictionary createDssDictionary(Iterable<byte[]> certificates, Iterable<byte[]> crls, Iterable<byte[]> ocspResponses) throws IOException
{
    final COSDictionary dssDictionary = new COSDictionary();
    dssDictionary.setNeedToBeUpdate(true);
    dssDictionary.setName(COSName.TYPE, "DSS");

    if (certificates != null)
        dssDictionary.setItem(COSName.getPDFName("Certs"), createArray(certificates));
    if (crls != null)
        dssDictionary.setItem(COSName.getPDFName("CRLs"), createArray(crls));
    if (ocspResponses != null)
        dssDictionary.setItem(COSName.getPDFName("OCSPs"), createArray(ocspResponses));

    return dssDictionary;
}

COSArray createArray(Iterable<byte[]> datas) throws IOException
{
    COSArray array = new COSArray();
    array.setNeedToBeUpdate(true);

    if (datas != null)
    {
        for (byte[] data: datas)
            array.add(createStream(data));
    }

    return array;
}

COSStream createStream(byte[] data) throws IOException
{
    RandomAccessBuffer storage = new RandomAccessBuffer();
    COSStream stream = new COSStream(storage);
    stream.setNeedToBeUpdate(true);
    final OutputStream unfilteredStream = stream.createUnfilteredStream();
    unfilteredStream.write(data);
    unfilteredStream.flush();
    return stream;
}
```

You can add such a DSS dictionary to your source document as an incremental update like this:

```java
try (   InputStream source = ...;
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(resultFile);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(resultFile);
        )
{
    byte[] inputBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(source);

    PDDocument pdDocument = PDDocument.load(new ByteArrayInputStream(inputBytes));
    PDDocumentCatalog catalog = pdDocument.getDocumentCatalog();
    catalog.getCOSObject().setNeedToBeUpdate(true);
    catalog.getCOSDictionary().setItem(COSName.getPDFName("DSS"), dss);

    fos.write(inputBytes);
    pdDocument.saveIncremental(fis, fos);
    pdDocument.close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that method but in the end the signatures become corrupted. The Adobe says that "there is a problem with the signatures"

Comment: Hhmmm, that is surprising. Can you share a sample failing output?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, Today I am not at the office but tomorrow I will post an sample. Thanks.

Comment: @Hugo Have you meanwhile had time to find the samples?

Comment: Hi. Sorry for the delay. Meanwhile I've started working in another project and this topic became less priority.
Thanks for your help. With your code and some minor changes I've added the necessary information to the DSS dictionary. Now the Adobe reader says that the signatures are LTV-enabled.
I''ve added an answer with the solution.

Comment: The `AddValidationInformation.java` example in the source code download does just that since earlier this year. Also recovation checking etc.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr That example (including its dependent classes) starts to have size and functionality beyond a mere example. You might consider moving much of it (together with probably much of the signing examples) into a core artifact, either pdfbox or a new one. One question, though: At first glance that example appears to collect revocation information for the signature signer and time stamp signer certificate chains only, not for the signers of the revocation information. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes I think so. I thought that the revocation list is signed by the issuer?

Comment: I don't think it is ready for being a subproject. The whole thing needs more "peer review". And I haven't even checked the logic against any RFCs.

Comment: @mkl I think I understand what you mean... that one should look at the issuer of the CRL, and if that one wasn't in the list, then do the same thing again, i.e. look for revocation of that issueing certificate?

Comment: *"I thought that the revocation list is signed by the issuer?"* - A CRL usually is (there are indirect lists, though) but ocsp responses usually are signed by special certificates. Often these certificates are marked to not require revocation checks but not always.

Comment: *"I think I understand what you mean"* - strictly speaking what I mean depends on the legal context of the ca. For example the exact validation requirements do differ between EU style validation and regular Adobe Reader style validation.

Comment: @mkl Thank you, I (hopefully, because I can't test it) fixed it for OCSP.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I added some comments to [PDFBOX-3017](https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3017?focusedCommentId=16694953&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-16694953).

Answer (score 2):

After analyzing the code again I've found some errors in the certificates encoding. I think that was the cause of the document corruption.
Bellow the code I've used to add the chain certificates to the DSS dictionary. I've reused your code. 
Thanks once again.

```
private byte[] addCertificates(byte[] pdfFile) throws IOException, PDFLTVEnablerException {

ByteArrayInputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(pdfFile);
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(stream);

PDDocumentCatalog catalog = document.getDocumentCatalog();
COSDictionary catalogDictionary = catalog.getCOSDictionary();

COSDictionary dssDictionary = (COSDictionary) catalogDictionary.getDictionaryObject("DSS");
dssDictionary.setNeedToBeUpdate(true);

COSArray certDSS = getTrustedCertificatesChain();

dssDictionary.setItem(COSName.getPDFName("Certs"), certDSS);

catalog.getCOSObject().setNeedToBeUpdate(true);
catalogDictionary.setItem(COSName.getPDFName("DSS"), dssDictionary);

File resultFile = File.createTempFile("dss", null);
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(resultFile);
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(resultFile);
fos.write(pdfFile);
try {
    document.saveIncremental(fis, fos);
} catch (COSVisitorException e) {
    logger.debug(e.getMessage());
    throw new PDFLTVEnablerException("Couldn't access PDF DSS dictionary");
}

FileInputStream out = new FileInputStream(resultFile);
byte[] byteArray = IOUtils.toByteArray(out);
resultFile.delete();
document.close();
return byteArray;
}

private byte[] addRevocationInfo(byte[] pdfFile) throws IOException, PDFLTVEnablerException {

ByteArrayInputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(pdfFile);
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(stream);

PDDocumentCatalog catalog = document.getDocumentCatalog();
COSDictionary catalogDictionary = catalog.getCOSDictionary();

COSDictionary dssDictionary = (COSDictionary) catalogDictionary.getDictionaryObject("DSS");
dssDictionary.setNeedToBeUpdate(true);

COSArray crlsDss = loadCrlsForCerts(pdfFile);

dssDictionary.setItem(COSName.getPDFName("CRLs"), crlsDss);
dssDictionary.setItem(COSName.getPDFName("OCSPs"), new COSArray());

catalog.getCOSObject().setNeedToBeUpdate(true);
catalogDictionary.setItem(COSName.getPDFName("DSS"), dssDictionary);

File resultFile = File.createTempFile("dss", null);
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(resultFile);
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(resultFile);
fos.write(pdfFile);
try {
    document.saveIncremental(fis, fos);
} catch (COSVisitorException e) {
    logger.debug(e.getMessage());
    throw new PDFLTVEnablerException("Couldn't access PDF DSS dictionary");

}

FileInputStream out = new FileInputStream(resultFile);
byte[] byteArray = IOUtils.toByteArray(out);
resultFile.delete();
document.close();
return byteArray;
}


private COSArray getTrustedCertificatesChain() throws IOException {

COSArray certs = new COSArray();
certs.setNeedToBeUpdate(true);

List < X509Certificate > trustedCerts = trustedCertsStore.getTrustedCerts();

for (X509Certificate cert: trustedCerts) {
    try {
        COSStream certStream = createStream(cert.getEncoded());
        certs.add(certStream);
    } catch (CertificateException e) {
        logger.error("Could not import trusted certificate: " + e.getMessage());
        throw new IOException("The certificate in the truststore is invalid");
    }
}

return certs;
}

private COSArray loadCrlsForCerts(byte[] pdfFile) throws IOException, PDFLTVEnablerException {
COSArray crls = new COSArray();
crls.setNeedToBeUpdate(true);

List < X509Certificate > trustedCerts = trustedCertsStore.getTrustedCerts();

for (X509Certificate cert: trustedCerts) {
    try {
        X509CRL crl = crlDownloader.verifyCertificateCRLs(cert);
        if (crl != null) {
            COSStream crlStream = createStream(crl.getEncoded());
            crls.add(crlStream);
        }
    } catch (CertificateException e) {
        logger.error("Could not import trusted certificate: " + e.getMessage());
        throw new IOException("The certificate in the truststore is invalid");
    } catch (CertificateVerificationException e) {
        logger.error("Could not import trusted certificate: " + e.getMessage());
        throw new IOException("The certificate in the truststore is invalid");
    } catch (CRLException e) {
        logger.debug("Error downloading crl " + e.getMessage());
        throw new Exception("Couldn't retrive CRL");
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        logger.debug(e.getMessage());
        throw new Exception("Couldn't retrive CRL");
    }
}
return crls;
}

public COSStream createStream(byte[] data) throws IOException {
RandomAccessBuffer storage = new RandomAccessBuffer();
COSStream stream = new COSStream(storage);
stream.setNeedToBeUpdate(true);
final OutputStream unfilteredStream = stream.createUnfilteredStream();
unfilteredStream.write(data);
unfilteredStream.flush();
return stream;
}
```

Comment: So if I understand your code correctly you get a valid LTV signature without adding OCSP information to the DSS?

Comment: Yes, but I add CRL's to the DSS dictionary.

Comment: @HugoAlves, have you a complete example of this ?

Answer (score 1):

Actually I hadn't used PDFbox directly.

I Start with an object of type PAdESService, My objective is to add a timestamp to a PDF.

I've constructed the DSS dictionary like this:

```
private PdfDict createDSSDictionary() throws IOException, CertificateEncodingException {

final PdfDict dssDictionary = factory.newDict("DSS");

for (X509Certificate x509Certificate : certs) {
    PdfStream stream = factory.newStream(x509Certificate.getEncoded());
    certArray.add(stream);
}

if (certArray.size() > 0) {
    dssDictionary.add("Certs", certArray);
}

if (crlArray.size() > 0) {
    dssDictionary.add("CRLs", crlArray);
}

if (ocspArray.size() > 0) {
    dssDictionary.add("OCSPs", ocspArray);
}
return dssDictionary;
}
```

This method only shows the construction of the Certs stream, the procedure for the OCSPs and CRLs is similar.

Then it comes the ugly part.

I've changed the class eu.europa.ec.markt.dss.parameter.SignatureParameters.
I've added the parameter PdfDict that contains the DSS dictionary that I want to insert in the PDF(the DSS is returned from the previous function).

Then in class eu.europa.ec.markt.dss.signature.pades.PAdESLevelBaselineLT
 I get the DSS dictionary from the signatureParameters and use it as parameter to extend the timsetamp(..) function of the class eu.europa.ec.markt.dss.signature.pdf.PDFTimestampService
.

Comment: As I see you have the certificates, CRLs, and OCSP responses in those sd-dss wrapper classes for PDF dictionaries and arrays. As you say yourself, you *hadn't used PDFbox directly.* Your question, on the other hand, sounds like you are looking for a solution using PDFBox directly (or you at least have no trouble using such a solution. Thus, I assume you have those certificates, CRLs, and OCSP responses in an unwrapped form, too.